# How do I connect to an office 365 calendar via vb.net

Tags: office365

I have an application where I want to read events from people's office 365 calendars.  I would like them to first share the calendar with me, then I would like to programatically iterate through all the calendars that are shared with me and read the events.

Questions:
1. Is this possible?
2. How do people share their calendars with me?
3. How do I connect through an API to read from these calendars?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

API info here. Sharing calendars can be done via Outlook's UI. https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn641957(v=exchg.150).aspx